# Locating the main website (front page) file in cpanel for website built on laravel and voyager

Tags: laravel, voyager

I am trying to locate the file or folder in cpanel that the front page of my website is housed in so i can add a floating action button script to my website.

I just have no prior experience here.

(I am trying to add this in correct place)

It should have a finished result as here http://www.floatingactionbutton.com

Answer (score 1):

The views or 'pages' of the application should be in the `resources/views/` directory.  You may find a view that is 'home' or something similar but there is no way of knowing what the views have been named when your application was developed.

The views may not be in straight HTML / PHP but rather use Laravel's Blade syntax.

In addition, existing javascript files in your site may have been compiled using Webpack.  I imagine the floating action button will be a javascript script.

Can you get the original developer to add the script for you?